# Magento2 : Composer Problem Could not find a matching version of package <name>. Check the package spelling, your version

Tags: magento2, composer

I have big problem and don't know how i made that mistake...

i wrote

`composer require searchanise/search-autocomplete`     and

Could not find a matching version of package searchanise/search-autocomplete. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

This is composer.json

```
{
    "name": "searchanise/search-autocomplete",
    "description": "Search Autocomplete + Search Suggest",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "homepage": "http://www.searchanise.com",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Simtech",
            "email": "sales@searchanise.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Searchanise\\SearchAutocomplete\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
  ]

}
```

Anyone can help me? :)

Thanks

Comment: I tried installing the searchanise/search-autocomplete module in a blank Magento 2 installation (running 2.2.5) and got an error saying the `searchanise/search-autocomplete could not be found in any version`
You have posted the composer.json for the searchanise/search-autocomplete module somehow, so it seems you have access to the module's source code. I think the issue may be in the module not being hosted on the repo.magento.com or public packagist repositories. You  should either set up a private local repository and pull the module from there or there's more to this story.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem (also with this extension). For anyone who is facing an issue with installing any Magento Marketplace extension with Composer: please check your auth.json for the correct credentials to connect with the Marketplace. The error about the version is misleading.

Please see the given answer here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Extensions/Problems-installing-extension-from-Marketplace/m-p/92732/highlight/true#M985

```
{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "<marketplace-public-key>",
         "password": "<marketplace-private-key>" 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where to find the auth.json?

Comment: @Black the auth.json file should be in the same directory as your composer.json file. If it is not there, you can create it. Please see [https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @MrPaulsky.
I changed auth.json.sample to auth.json and add username, password. it helped me fix this: 
  Could not find a matching version of package stripe/stripe-payments. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

Answer (score 3):

Add in 2 lines your composer.json file
**"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true**
Do not forget to release your project from github https://prnt.sc/qigw57
**Register or login on https://packagist.org/ and connect your git account.**
after login, press the submit button from the header and enter your git Repository URL.
after added successfully your repository you can install your module by composer require searchanise/search-autocomplete
I'll be pleased if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

add extension in your cart https://marketplace.magento.com/klarna-m2-checkout.html here and purchase (it's free anyways but still don't skip this part) then use access keys which you have on that account in your auth json

```
"repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "firstKey",
            "password": "secondKey"
        },
```

then install the extension with composer. mention any version which suits you, write version number after " : "

```
composer require "klarna/m2-checkout:^9.3.2" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or if you use docker

```
 dockergento composer require "klarna/m2-checkout:^9.3.2" --ignore-platform-reqs
```